# scala.MatchError on a tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-graphx

After processing some input data, I got a RDD[(String, String, Long)], say *input*,  in hand.

```
input: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, Long)] = MapPartitionsRDD[9] at flatMap at <console>:54
```

The string fields here represent vertices of graph and long field is the weight of the edge.

To create a graph out of this, first I am inserting vertices into a map with a unique id if vertex is not known already. If it was already encountered, I use the vertex id that was assigned previously. Essentially, each vertex is assigned a unique id of type Long and then I want to create Edges.

Here is what I am doing:

```
var vertexMap = collection.mutable.Map[String, Long]()
var vid : Long = 0          // global vertex id counter
var srcVid : Long = 0       // source vertex id
var dstVid : Long = 0       // destination vertex id

val graphEdges = input.map {
    case Row(src: String, dst: String, weight: Long) => (
        if (vertexMap.contains(src)) {
            srcVid = vertexMap(src)
            if (vertexMap.contains(dst)) {
                dstVid = vertexMap(dst)
            } else {
                vid += 1   // pick a new vertex id
                vertexMap += (dst -> vid)
                dstVid = vid
            }
            Edge(srcVid, dstVid, weight)
        } else {
            vid += 1
            vertexMap(src) = vid
            srcVid = vid
            if (vertexMap.contains(dst)) {
                dstVid = vertexMap(dst)
            } else {
                vid += 1
                vertexMap(dst) = vid
                dstVid = vid
            }
            Edge(srcVid, dstVid, weight)
        }
    }

val graph = Graph.fromEdges(graphEdges, 0)
println("num edges = " + graph.numEdges);
println("num vertices = " + graph.numVertices);
```

What I see is

graphEdges is of type RDD[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[Long]] and graph is of type Graph[Int,Long]

```
graphEdges: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[Long]] = MapPartitionsRDD[10] at map at <console>:64
graph: org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph[Int,Long] = org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl@1b48170a
```

but I get the following error, while printing the graph's edge and vertex count.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 9, localhost, executor driver): ***scala.MatchError: (vertexA, vertexN, 2000
)*** (of class scala.Tuple3)
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:64)
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:64)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:844)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:844)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1038)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't understand where is the mismatch here.

Thanks @Joe K for the helpful tip. I started using zipIndex and code looks compact now, however graph instantiation still fails. Here is the updated code:

```
val vertices = input.map(r => r._1).union(input.map(r => r._2)).distinct.zipWithIndex
val graphEdges = input.map {
    case (src, dst, weight) =>
        Edge(vertices.lookup(src)(0), vertices.lookup(dst)(0), weight)
}
val graph = Graph.fromEdges(graphEdges, 0)
println("num edges = " + graph.numEdges);
```

So, from the original 3-tuple, I am forming a union of 1st and 2nd tuples (which are vertices), then assigning unique Ids to each after uniquifying them. I am then using their ids, while creating edges. However, it fails with following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 23, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks
 a SparkContext. It could happen in the following cases:
(1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed
inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
(2) When a Spark Streaming job recovers from checkpoint, this exception will be hit if a reference to an RDD not defined by the streaming job is used in DStream operations. For more information, See SPARK-13758.
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$sc(RDD.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.lookup(PairRDDFunctions.scala:937)
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:55)
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:53)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:107)
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific error is coming from trying to match a tuple as a `Row`, which it is not.

Change:

```
case Row(src: String, dst: String, weight: Long) => {
```

to just:

```
case (src, dst, weight) => {
```

Also, your larger plan for generating vertex ids will not work. All of the logic inside the `map` will happen in parallel in different executors, which will have different copies of the mutable map.

You should `flatMap` your edges to get a list of all vertexes, then call `.distinct.zipWithIndex` to assign each vertex a single unique long value. You would then need to re-join with the original edges.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error here. I made more progress based on your suggestion with zipWithIndex .. however the graph instantiation fails still:

Comment: sorry I couldn't post update in the comments .. hence updated the original post. Graph instantiation still fails. Appreciate the help.